# Inserting Data From Database Into View - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

Okay, so I'm grabbing the data I need properly from the database. However, how do I take the "echo data" and echo it as a variable in my view?

For example,

```
<? echo $row1->title; ?>
```

is not working when placed in the view.

Here's a portion of my controller:

```
// Pricing and package details insert from db
    $query = $this -> db -> query('SELECT title, price, number_sites, number_entries, white_label FROM pricing');

    $row1 = $query->row(0); // 0 grabs first row in table: Package 1         

    echo $row1->title;
    echo $row1->price;
    echo $row1->number_sites;
```

If you want to view the entire controller, check it here:
http://codepad.org/4nRrywzl

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass through the data from the controller to the view.

Currently you are passing `$data` to the view, add another field in this array for the row.

```
$data['row1'] = $row1;
$this->load->view('shared/header_view', $data); // or any other view
```

and this should work in the view

```
echo $row1->$title;
```

Not tested the code above - but it should work.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that originally, but I get an error: "Message: Undefined variable: row1" and "Message: Trying to get property of non-object" in the view.

Comment: Remember to assign the variable to the array you are sending to the view

Comment: The error you received on your earlier attempt and quoted in your comment was likely to have been caused by the variable not being assigned to the `$data` array.

Comment: I did that...I had the $data assigned to the load->view from before... http://codepad.org/4nRrywzl

Comment: I may also be confused as to what your referring too. Care to map it out?

Comment: Yes you have.  But you are not assigning `$row1` to `$data` in your code.  You need to do this, if you want to use the variable in a view.

Comment: Hmm...here's my updated copy...http://codepad.org/Vpv17kZd ...have I not assigned $row1??

Comment: you're wiping out the data array when you do $data = array(....

Try putting $data[row1] = $row1 after that statement.  Also you should be making the database call in a model not in your controller.  You can read about models here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html

Comment: Thanks Will! I tired that and it's still not working. New error now (Undefined property: stdClass::$Subscription). How would you write this in - based on this controller: http://codepad.org/dkPBQtbL Also, just for the sake of troubleshooting this I put the database call in the controller. I'll move to Model once functional.